# Add iFrame macro to Umbraco

Tags: html, xml, xslt, iframe, umbraco

I am adding a XSLT for adding iFrame in Umbraco.

Here is my XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xsl:stylesheet [ <!ENTITY nbsp "&#x00A0;"> ]>
<xsl:stylesheet
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:msxml="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
  xmlns:umbraco.library="urn:umbraco.library" xmlns:Exslt.ExsltCommon="urn:Exslt.ExsltCommon" xmlns:Exslt.ExsltDatesAndTimes="urn:Exslt.ExsltDatesAndTimes" xmlns:Exslt.ExsltMath="urn:Exslt.ExsltMath" xmlns:Exslt.ExsltRegularExpressions="urn:Exslt.ExsltRegularExpressions" xmlns:Exslt.ExsltStrings="urn:Exslt.ExsltStrings" xmlns:Exslt.ExsltSets="urn:Exslt.ExsltSets" xmlns:seoChecker.MetaData="urn:seoChecker.MetaData" xmlns:PS.XSLTsearch="urn:PS.XSLTsearch"
  exclude-result-prefixes="msxml umbraco.library Exslt.ExsltCommon Exslt.ExsltDatesAndTimes Exslt.ExsltMath Exslt.ExsltRegularExpressions Exslt.ExsltStrings Exslt.ExsltSets seoChecker.MetaData PS.XSLTsearch ">

<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="currentPage"/>
<xsl:variable name="location" select="/macro/location"/>
<xsl:variable name="width" select="/macro/width"/>
<xsl:variable name="height" select="/macro/height"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
  <iframe src="{$location}" width="{$width}" height="{$height}" type="text/html" frameborder="0">
Sorry, your browser does not support IFRAMES
</iframe>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Apprently when I add the macro to the form and run the page it throws an error

```
Error reading XSLT file: iFrameContactUs.xslt
```

I have followed steps from this [link](http://www.smickus.org/inserting-iframes-with-the-umbraco-cms/#sthash.duoM9q8a.dpbs)

Steps followed

- I first created an XSLT file in the Developer section in umbraco.
- Then I added parameters to the same XSLT in the macro section (location, width and height).
- Now, I went to the settings tab and then navigated to the page and added this to the html

@Umbraco.RenderMacro("IFrameContactUs", new {height="700px", location="url of the page", width="500px"})

But, when I run the code i get the error saying

> Error reading XSLT

Could someone tell me what is wrong in the XSLT and why it is not running in my website

Comment: Which Umbraco version is this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Umbraco specific XSLT extensions have been removed in version 7, that's why it's failing.

Instead, go to Developer -> Partial View Macro Files and create one there instead. Remember to leave the check mark in "Create Macro".

Insert the following in the file:

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Macros.PartialViewMacroPage
<iframe src="@Model.MacroParameters["location"]" width="@Model.MacroParameters["width"]" height="@Model.MacroParameters["height"]" type="text/html" frameborder="0">
Sorry, your browser does not support IFRAMES
</iframe>
```

Add the same parameters to the actual macro as before, and it should work exactly as planned (and it's even short and readable) ;-)